# wget download only url with specific words in it

Tags: wget

how to make wget download ONLY an url that contains the exact words?

example
https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=500

I want wget to only download html pages like this.
https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=

so basically

https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=500

https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=501

https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=502

https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=503

all the way up to id=500000000

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash 4.0+

`wget https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id={500..500000000}`

Older Bash

```
for i in {500..500000000}
do
    wget "https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=$i"
done
```

CMD pasting in window:

`for /l %x in (500, 1, 500000000) do wget "https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=%x"`

CMD batch file:

`for /l %%x in (500, 1, 500000000) do wget "https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=%%x"`

Comment: Hmm I couldnt figure out how to use this in cmd? Im completely new to this :/ 

when I:

wget "https://ragnarok-europe.net/?module=item&action=view&id=$i"

he downloads only 1 page and is done

my bad I should have mentioned that Im on windows

Comment: Ah, didnt realize you were using cmd, I will post a third solution for that

Comment: @DA updated for cmd use case

Comment: perfect bro. thank you it worked!

Comment: @DA, then you should give him an upvote.

Comment: @user136036 i did? 

but it says: 

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @DA Ah interesting, did not know that, I just saw a rating of "0", so I gave him an upvote :) Have an upvote too.